# How can i use a function inside of another function

Tags: python

I am currently playing around with classes and functions since i am not familiar with python and i would like to know how i can get `addy(self, addx)` to call addx.

```
class test:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def addx(self):
        y = self.x + 10
        return y

    def addy(self, addx):
        z = addx() + 10
        return z

one = test(1)
print(one.addy())
```

> line 15, in  print(one.addy()) TypeError: addy() missing 1
>   required positional argument: 'addx' Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What output would you expect? 21?

Comment: Why does `addy` have a `addx` parameter but you're not passing any arguments to it when you call it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `self` from within a class method.
`self.addx()`

Also the `addx` parameter on this line shouldn't be there:
`def addy(self, addx):`

I think this is what you are going for:

```
class test:
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

  def addx(self):
    y = self.x + 10
    return y

  def addy(self):
    z = self.addx() + 10
    return z

one = test(1)
print(one.addy())
```

Comment: lol, thanks for the edit help.  And yeah, it's not clear whether OP just made a mistake in his original question.

Answer (score 3):

You've overcomplicated things by wrapping it in a class. Take it out and it'll work (mostly) the way you expect.

```
def add10(x):
    return x+10

def add20(x):
    return add10(add10(x))
```

Since you've wrapped it in the class you've complicated the namespace. It's no longer called `addx` or `addy`, so using those names throws a `NameError`. You have to use the qualified name instead.

```
class FooBar():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10

    def addx(self):
        return self.x + 10  # Note the `self.` before the attribute...

    def addy(self):
        return self.addx() + 10  # ...and also before the method name.
```

Methods are always passed their owning object as a first argument when called, which is why we've got `def addx(self):` but then call with `self.addx()`

Comment: As is explicitly mentioned in [the official Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks) - the last paragraphs of "9.4 Random Remarks": "Methods may call other methods by using method attributes of the `self` argument:..."

Answer (score -1):

If you are attempting to relate `addx` in the signature of `addy` to the method `addx`, you can pass the string name of the method and use `getattr`:

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x
  def addx(self):
    y = self.x + 10
    return y
  def addy(self, func):
    z = getattr(self, func)() + 10
    return z

s = Test(3)
print(s.addy('addx'))
```